# Is there an equivalent to the RAGG graphics device for PDF output in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I recently stumbled upon the blog post on the updated graphics device RAGG for raster graphics in R. It's truly amazing; you can mix and match fonts as you please:

```r
p <- ggplot() +
  labs(title = "Title set in Fira Sans ") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(family = "Fira Sans"))

ggsave("~/Desktop/fira_sans.png", plot = p, device = agg_png)
```

yields
[image: ragg_png]

So I am wondering if it is possible to achieve the same with PDF output? I do understand that RAGG is a device for *raster* graphics only.

Calling `ggsave()` to save as PDF without specifying a graphics device returns the error message "invalid font type". Specifying `device = cairo_pdf` correctly sets the text in Fira Sans but omits the emoji (for which I assume some sort of font fallback would have to be in place).

```r
ggsave("~/Desktop/fira_sans.pdf", plot = p, device = cairo_pdf)
```

yields

[image: cairo_pdf]

Comment: I think the emoji is present in the PDF file: copy and paste or  `pdftools::pdf_text("fira_sans.pdf")` shows it.  The problem is with the viewer, which doesn't know how to render it.  Not sure why that is, I thought `cairo_pdf` embedded fonts.